Confirmation my grandmother was an identical twin and why she didn't have the BRCA gene?
There's been a long unanswered question in my family until recently. My grandmother had a twin sister who looked very similar but no one knew if they were identical twins or fraternal. My grandmother passed in the 1990's in her 70's and her sister died young when she was in her 40's due to breast cancer. She likely had the BRCA gene since her daughter inherited the gene.
So back to my grandmother. Let's call her P and her twin sister, R. P's daughter and R's son both sent their DNA to ancestry. On ancestry it shows P's daughter and R's son as a likely half siblings - Shared DNA: 1,917 cM across 54 segments. I was told that since the shared DNA is 1,917 (more than some number) then P and R were identical twins.
Using this information here, can I assume this to be true? It looks to be a very high probability.
I'm also trying to understand how R had the BRCA gene and P didn't. I assume identical twins don't have exactly the same genes.
UPDATE: Sorry, didn't mention P's daughter (my mother) tested negative for the BRCA gene.

Hi, and welcome to Medical Sciences! You said: "I assume identical twins don't have exactly the same genes." Why assume? Finding confirmation of that is easy, and this site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research. For the reasons mentioned in this meta post, this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links or references to what you've found in your search.

Wondering two things here: how do you know that your grandmother didn't have the BRCA gene (what am I missing in the Q?), and, by definition, does everyone with the gene get breast cancer?

Thank you both. @CareyGregory I updated the post a bit with what I had found previously. anongoodnurse your questions are on point and I guess you asking them answers my questions. I don't know that P didn't have the BRCA gene. I was assuming so since she didn't die of cancer and P's daughter didn't have it, but both of my answers don't matter since P could have had it and didn't get cancer nor pass is on.

Oh, I missed somehow that P's daughter tested negative for the gene. Where is that stated? (Sorry, I can't see it.)

To be more direct, BRCA1/2 increases your chances of getting BrCa, but it's not an absolute; the more harmful the mutation, the more likely the chance of cancer. Also, it's possible that second, non-genetic mutation occurred in R that increased the negative effect of the BRCA gene.

Oof! I just realized I made a nonsensicaql mistake (well, nonsense to me anyway.) I meant a non-hereditary (acquired) mutation, i.e. well post-zygotic

The half-siblings result is your best evidence that they're identical twins. Identical twins share effectively all the same DNA, except for mutations they accumulate in their lifetime starting at immediately after they separated.
It's possible neither had a BRCA mutation; you can die young of cancer without it, and the BRCA allele in P's daughter could have come from the other parent unless you know their genotype, too.
It's possible both had a BRCA mutation, you can live to old age without cancer with it; with one copy, there's a 50/50 chance to pass it on to a child, and the chance is independent with each child, so you could have a BRCA allele yet have several kids without it.
Finally, there's possibility for de novo mutation; not likely and the other explanations are simple and more probable, though.

Good answer. The second paragraph is an important point.

Thank you. All good points. All I know is that R died of cancer at 41 (but we don't know if she had the BRCA gene). We know her daughter had it but as you said it could have come from her father.  We don't know that P had or didn't have the BRCA gene, just that her daughter (my mother) doesn't have the gene.
